# How do I wait for a pull?

Tags: node.js, docker, bluebird

I need to run a container from node so I'm using the `dockerode` module, which uses the Docker API.  To run a container I first need to pull the image (if it doesn't exist locally).  I've *promisified* the calls for simplicity but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to connect the calls, particularly with respect to the callback that `pull` offers.  here's what I have:

```
init: function(opts) {
    var self = this;
    self.docker = new Docker();
    self.pull = Bluebird.promisify(
        self.docker.pull, { context: self.docker }
    );  
    self.createContainer = Bluebird.promisify(
        self.docker.createContainer, { context: self.docker }
    );  
},  

run: function(opts) {
    var self = this;
    return self.createContainer(opts).catch(function(e) {
        return self.pull(opts.Image).then(function(stream) {
            return self.createContainer(opts);
        }); 
    }).then(function(o) {;
        var start = Bluebird.promisify(
            o.start, { context: o } 
        );  
        return start({});
    }).then(function(o) {;
        var inspect = Bluebird.promisify(
            o.inspect, {context: o}
        );  
        return inspect();
    }); 
},
```

so what happens is the first `createContainer` fails (because the image hasn't been loaded yet) and a call to `pull` happens.  when that succeeds, `createContainer` is called.

at present that call is failing because the image didn't yet get time to load.  I see in the docs: https://github.com/apocas/dockerode (see Helper Functions) that I can do:

```
        return self.pull(opts.Image).then(function(stream) {
            self.docker.modem.followProgress(stream, function(err, output) {
                return self.createContainer(opts);
            });
        });
```

...which I think means `createContainer` will only fire when the pull has finished, but the problem is I've broken the promises.  what's the correct way of dealing with this?

TIA - e

*** RESOLVED ***

as per Joshua's answer below, here's working code:

```
init: function(opts) {
    var self = this;
    self.docker = new Docker();
    self.pull = Bluebird.promisify(
        self.docker.pull, {context: self.docker}
    );  
    self.createContainer = Bluebird.promisify(
        self.docker.createContainer, {context: self.docker}
    );  
    self.followProgress = Bluebird.promisify(
        function(stream, done) {
            return self.docker.modem.followProgress(stream, done);
        },  
        {context: self.docker.modem}
    );  
},  
run: function(opts) {
    var self = this;
    return self.createContainer(opts).catch(function(e) {
        return self.pull(opts.Image).then(function(stream) {
            return self.followProgress(stream);
        }).then(function() {
            return self.createContainer(opts);
        }); 
    }).then(function(o) {
        var start = Bluebird.promisify(
            o.start, {context: o}
        );  
        start();
        return o;
    }).then(function(o) {;
        var inspect = Bluebird.promisify(
            o.inspect, {context: o}
        );
        return inspect();
    });
},
```

I'm only not happy that the result of `start()` is getting lost but if I want to inspect after running I need `o` and I don't know how to handle both.  but the above works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking in generalities here, suppose you have:

```
return createsPromiseA().then((a) => {
  takesNodebackB(a, (err, b) => {
    let promiseC = createsPromiseC();
    // How do I return promiseC??
  });
});
```

There are 2 answers. One uses what comes with native promises ootb:

```
return createsPromiseA().then((a) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    takesNodebackB(a, (err, b) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(b);
    });
  });
}).then((b) => createsPromiseC());
```

The trick here is wrapping the nodeback function in a promise.

The second answer is that bluebird ships with http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html which, while I haven't used it, *should* allow you to do the same thing, something like:

```
return createsPromiseA()
  .then((a) => bluebird.promisify(takesNodebackB)(a))
  .then((b) => createsPromiseC());
```